# How do i Dequeue a queue

Tags: c#, queue

Suppose

```
Queue<String> aQueue =new Queue<string>();
Customer aCustomer=new Customer();
```

and   I Enqueue `aCustomer` into Queue with `aCustomer`.(Several value )

how can I Deque `aCustomer` and place those value in to `aCustomer`.(Several Variable ).

Please Help me if any one have the solution.

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to accomplish by pushing property values from an object onto a queue? You are much more likely to get good answers if you explain why you are doing this.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Enqueue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t249c2y7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`Dequeue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1c8bzx97%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
Queue<Customer> aQueue =new Queue<Customer>();
Customer aCustomer=new Customer();

aQueue.Enqueue(aCustomer);
aCustomer = aQueue.Dequeue();
```

Comment: I'm sorry But That wouldn't possible ;

Comment: @user3245548: Can you explain that?

Comment: @PatrickHofman why do you change type of `aQueue`?
This is not what OP is needed, I think.

Comment: @Fyodor: because it else won't compile. I thought this was what the OP wanted. That's why I asked OP to clarify.

Comment: Don't you think that OP really has property of type `string` in his `Customer` type and he wants to add this property to the `aQueue`? I mean actually it is pretty unclear what he is asking. So how could you pretend to answer the question if it is unclear?

Comment: @Fyodor: because I thought it was clear to me...

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
Queue<Customer> aQueue = new Queue<Customer>();
Customer customer = new Customer { Name = "Test" };
aQueue.Enqueue(customer);
customer = new Customer { Name = "Test1" };
aQueue.Enqueue(customer);
customer = new Customer { Name = "Test2" };
aQueue.Enqueue(customer);

while (aQueue.Any())
{
    customer = aQueue.Dequeue();
    // use customer
}
```